# How to extract values from an object in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have recorded values at different moments and had a linear interpolation done within those points using the approx() function. I got the predicted values in the "model 1" object (please see the script below), but I couldn't find out how to extract those x,y predicted values from the object. Any help will be really appreciated.

Here is the script.

```
x <- c(7,56,64,71,84,92,98,106,118,140,148) # observed data
y <-c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.891038658,0.727258549,0) # observed data


par(mfrow = c(1,1))
plot(x, y, main = "approx(.)")
points(approx(x, y, method = "linear"), col = 4, pch = "*")
Model1<-approx(x, y, method="linear", xout=7:148, yleft=0, yright=0, rule =    1, f = 0, ties = mean)
```

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Comment: `print (Model1)`. If its a list of some elements, then you can extract it like `Model1$pred` or `Model1$confusion_matrix`

Comment: Also, if you just want `Model1` as a data frame (rather than as a list), you can do `Model1 = as.data.frame(Model1)`. Also, to see the structure of an R object, you can do `str(Model1)`, which will show you each list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`approx` is a simple function without complicated returns. It gives a list with two variables: `x` (taken from `xout` in `approx`) and `y` (interpolated values).

You can use `Model1$x` and `Model1$y` to access two vectors. If you want a data frame, as @eipi10 says, do:

```
as.data.frame(Model1)
```

which uses "list" method of generic function `as.data.frame`.